# error using styles in dynamic modules - android app bundle

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I'm using the app bundle - dynamic module in my android app. In the project I have a main module and a sub module. In sub module's values -> styles.xml , I have defined custom styles to enable some animations to activities.

```
<style name="SampleActivityTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/CustomButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@transition/activity_transition_note</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitTransition">@transition/activity_transition_note</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
</style>
```

In manifest, I'm using this styles using theme attribute,

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.SampleActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale"
        android:label=""
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SampleActivityTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

But when I build the project, I'm getting compile error like below,

```
/Users/chathura/Branches/AppBundle/sample_module/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:778: error: resource style/SampleActivityTheme (aka lk.sample.mysampleapp:style/SampleActivityTheme) not found.
```

What will be reason to this issue?

Any suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: @Pierre tried it and its turns out to red color. - can not resolve symbol... Have you  used styles in a sub module before?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my previous comment because I could not edit it. I posted the answer below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Referencing resources from dynamic features from the manifest is not supported today in the Android Gradle Plugin.

One of the reasons is that the manifests of all dynamic features get merged in the manifest of the base module, and the base module should not depend on the dynamic features.

If you define the style in the base, that should fix it.

Source:

From https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/dynamic-delivery

> The manifest for your app’s base module is similar to that of any
>   other app module. Keep in mind, when Google Play generates your app’s
>   base APK, it merges manifests for all modules into that of the base
>   APK.

Comment: This might be the reason. But I could not find any documentation about this. could you please post a link of docs that you got this details?

Comment: For me that is still a bug or at least not a good design. Because that means, that I can't add any theme from the dynamic feature module itself to the corresponding android manifest?!

Comment: That's a limitation of the Android platform. Even if it gets fixed in a recent version, you still need to support all older versions for devices that haven't upgraded yet.

Comment: @Pierre K, thanks for the fast response. But I don't quite understand why it's a limitation of the android platform. I thought it is "just" about what components, modules and files are build for certain type of app (instant, installed, density, etc). And with the now deprecated `com.android.feature` module it worked.  Which is maybe a totally different approach of building... I don't know...

Comment: `com.android.feature` was built for instant apps, and those aren't executed by the native platform, that's why there was more "flexibility".

Comment: If you try to reference a resource from the manifest inside the dynamic feature, then  you get the same error. why does this not work? The manifest gets merged I know.
But for example a widget should not be defined in the base/app module. It should only be available in the installable module. But this is somehow not possible.
This new architecture is just like the previous one. Again you have to put almost everything in the base/app module. And again you have issues maintaining the app size